# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) ([nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting)

Tags: node.js, express

```
fs.readFile("./Files/success-2021-10-16.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw new Error("Testing error messages here...");
      var array = data.toString().split("\n");
      var file_Data = [];

      for (i in array) {
        file_Data = array[i];
        file_Data = file_Data.replace(/'/g, '"');
        file_Data = JSON.parse(file_Data);
        console.log(file_Data);
      }
    });
```

please give me some Solution to solve that issue. Here is my code as well. I am working on Node.js

Comment: Hypothesis: the data is *not JSON*. (Next; identify *what* the failing value is to confirm or reject.)

Comment: `file_Data` is JS object not a JSON

Comment: In any case, without a sample of the failing data (eg. the value of `file_Data` when the error occurs), this question lacks sufficient debugging details.